# How to install AWS SAM Local on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, ubuntu-16.04, serverless, sam

I am trying to install AWS SAM (Serverless Application Model) Local on Ubuntu 16.04.

I tried to install SAM Local using NPM with the following command.

```
npm install -g aws-sam-local
```

I got the following error.

[image]

Please help me to sort it out?

Answer (score 4):

Installation on Ubuntu 16.04/18.04

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip -y
sudo -H python3 -m pip install aws-sam-cli
```

Answer (score 2):

First try

```
npm config set unsafe-perm=true
```

I also installed node v8.11.1

Answer (score 1):

The standard shebang for node is `#!/usr/bin/env node`. There is a package conflict with the name **node**, so it's named **nodejs**.

You can solve the issue with a symlink using alternatives.

`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/node node /usr/bin/nodejs 10`

Comment: It got resolved using this command                                                         ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node

Comment: The update alternatives approach does works by installing a symlink as well.

Answer (score 0):

first try

```
npm install -g go-npm
```

then 
`npm install -g aws-sam-local`

Answer (score 0):

If issue with current user permissions, please use **sudo** with below commands
First try,

**npm config set unsafe-perm=true**

Then,

**npm install -g go-npm**

finally,
 **npm install -g aws-sam-local**

It will also work for mac.